# Problem using MLP function from package RSNNS in R

Tags: regression, neural-networks

im trying to use a MLP to estimate a non-linear function, but for some reason, the ANN is giving me weights that make every input a single value of output. Looks like its estimating by just a constant. In fact this is happening even for very simple examples, like a linear regression with white noise. RBF works just fine every time.

I know that for a linear regression i could use some analitical approach or simply the lms algorithm, this is just a example where MLP should work but im doing something wrong. I tried different activation functions, learning parameters, number of hidden layers and so on. I also tried with different polynomials and MLP always returns me a weighed matrix that converges to a constant near the unconditional mean of the training data.

```
library(RSNNS)  
set.seed(1)  
e<-rnorm(500,sd=100)

x<-seq(1:500)

y<-2*x+e

model_mlp<-mlp(x,y,size=c(1),maxit=1000,initFunc="Randomize_Weights",initFuncParams=c(-0.1,0.1),learnFunc="Std_Backpropagation",learnFuncParams=c(0.1,0),hiddenActFunc="Act_Logistic",linOut=TRUE)

predictions_mlp<-predict(model_mlp,t(t(x)))  
plot(predictions_mlp,type="l")  
lines(y,col="2")

model_rbf<-rbf(x, y, size = c(50), maxit = 1000,initFunc = "RBF_Weights", initFuncParams = c(0, 1, 0, 0.02, 0.04),learnFunc = "RadialBasisLearning", learnFuncParams = c(1e-05, 0, 1e-05,0.1, 0.8), linOut = TRUE)

predictions_rbf<-predict(model_rbf,t(t(x)))  
plot(predictions_rbf,type="l")  
lines(y,col="2")
```

I couldnt find this doubt in another topic, sorry if its repeated and sorry about the english.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
model_mlp<-mlp(x,y,size=c(1),maxit=1000,learnFunc="Rprop",linOut=TRUE)
predictions_mlp<-predict(model_mlp,t(t(x)))   # now gives 500 unique predictions
```

Backpropagation seems extremely sensitive to the learning parameters while Rprop doesn't. If you still want to use backpropagation you should play with your learning rates more.

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that you might want to standardize your data before running backprop